# DQN+CPLEX: my program is getting slower with iteration goes

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

This program combines the DQN algorithm based on TensorFlow and the CPLEX solver in Matlab. The purpose is to find an optimal operation control strategy for energy storage based on deep reinforcement learning. DQN is used for energy storage systems. CPLEX solves the microgrid planning and scheduling problem (Mixed Integer Linear Programming). The main problem now is that the program iterates very quickly at the beginning, but may iterate to `EPSIOD = 100` or so, the running speed starts to decrease significantly, so that the final desired result cannot be obtained.

For the DQN algorithm, I directly used a program framework that has been written by others. The application scenario is the CartPole-v0 game in OpenAI Gym. The code URL is: https://github.com/ljpzzz/machinelearning/blob/master/reinforcement-learning/dqn.py

In my python program, the `matlab.engine` module is used to call the CPLEX solver in matlab to solve the microgrid planning problem. The parameters returned are used by the DQN algorithm for storage and use. Each iteration (`for episode in range (EPISODE + 1):`) will advance the `STEP` step (`for step in range (1, STEP + 1):`). Each iteration first calls the Matlab function (`engine.MILP_1`) for initial planning. And then calls the matlab function for planning adjustment (`engine.Reward_MILP2`) even further, and its specific use position is shown in the figure below.

[image]

[image]

It is worth noting that I previously replaced the CPLEX in this program with Matlab's power flow solver MATPOWER to calculate the 33-node power flow (another project). In this case, the entire program can always maintain a relatively ideal speed, and iterate to `EPISODE = 20000` times without any problem.

Tried method:

1. Adjust the CPLEX program written in MATLAB. This part of the program was relatively simple at first, and the solution was fast.
2. Call the `gc` module, adding `gc.disable()` and `gc.enable()` before and after the main for-loop.
3. Added `reset_default_graph()` in the `create_Q_network` function, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

However, the above methods cannot be used separately and in combination. Is there any way to keep this program running at a good speed? Many thanks!

Here is my main code :

```
# Hyper Parameters
EPISODE = 3000 #Episode limitation
STEP = 24  # Step limitation in an episode
TEST = 24  # The number of experiment test every 100 episode
T= 24        

def main():
    agent = DQN()
    P_sc_max = 500
    k1 = 11
    P_be_max = 500
    k2 = 51
    P_sc_ini1, P_be_ini1 = engine.CHESS_discrete(P_sc_max, k1, P_be_max, k2, nargout=2)
    P_be_ini=P_be_ini1[0]

    workbook_test = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')

    worksheet_test= workbook_test.add_sheet('test_data')

    for episode in range(EPISODE+1):
        total_reward = 0.0

        load_MG_pre,PV,PV_pre,WT,WT_pre,P_wt,P_wt_pre,pric_b,pric_b_pre,pric_s,pric_s_pre,pric_ob,pric_os= ini()
        SoC_mg_0 = 0.5
        SoC_be_0 = 0.1 * random.randint(3, 7)
        state =np.concatenate(([1],[SoC_be_0],[pric_b_pre[0]],[0]))
        P_b_station_pre, P_s_station_pre = engine.MILP_1(SoC_be_0,
                                                         SoC_mg_0,
                                                         matlab.double(load_MG_pre[0:24]),
                                                         matlab.double(PV_pre[0:24]),
                                                         matlab.double(WT_pre[0:24]),
                                                         matlab.double(pric_b_pre[0:24]),
                                                         matlab.double(pric_s_pre[0:24]),
                                                         nargout=2)
        state[3] = P_b_station_pre - P_s_station_pre

        SoC_be=SoC_be_0
        P_b_station=P_b_station_pre
        P_s_station=P_s_station_pre
        SoC_mg=SoC_mg_0

        gc.disable()

        num_step=0
        for step in range(1,STEP+1):
            action = agent.egreedy_action(state)  
            P_be=P_be_ini[action]

            reward, P_station, SoC_be_new, P_b_station_new, P_s_station_new, SoC_mg_new, done = engine.Reward_MILP2(   
                P_be, SoC_be,P_b_station,P_s_station,
                pric_b[step - 1],pric_s[step - 1],
                pric_ob[step - 1],pric_os[step - 1],
                SoC_mg,
                matlab.double(load_MG_pre[step - 1:step + 23]),
                matlab.double(PV_pre[step - 1:step + 23]),
                matlab.double(WT_pre[step - 1:step + 23]),
                matlab.double(pric_b_pre[step - 1:step + 23]),
                matlab.double(pric_s_pre[step - 1:step + 23]),
                nargout=7)

            SoC_be=SoC_be_new
            P_b_station =P_b_station_new
            P_s_station =P_s_station_new
            P_MG = P_b_station_new - P_s_station_new
            SoC_mg = SoC_mg_new

next_state=np.concatenate(([1+step],[SoC_be],[pric_b[step]],[P_MG]))
            agent.perceive(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            state = next_state
            total_reward += reward
            num_step += 1
            if done:
                break
        gc.enable()

        if episode % 100 == 0:
            ave_reward = total_reward / TEST
            worksheet_test.write(0,int(episode / 100), ave_reward)
            worksheet_test.write(1, int(episode / 100), num_step)
            workbook_test.save('Test_data.xls')

    workbook_test.save('Test_data.xls')
    x2 = xlrd.open_workbook("Test_data.xls")
    sheet2 = x2.sheet_by_name("test_data")

    for i in range(0, int(EPISODE / 100) + 1):
        print('episode: ', i, 'Evaluation Average Reward:', sheet2.row(0)[i].value)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the code as **text**, not as *images*.